Im using mat-slide-toggle but it is not showing like in angular/material documentation
Here is in angular material documentation
And here is in my project
Why cant i have the slide toggle like the first image.
I need to show the slide toggle like in the angular material documentation, i dont know why in my project the component is just a button type switch and does not have the angular material style

It is because it is an experimental code and you must import the @angular/material-experimental dependencies and configure them
Follow the dependency configuration guide https://material.angular.io/guide/material-3

I think you might be facing the same problem as me. Try looking at this question and my (finally discovered) answer to it: How can I make my mat-slide-toggle follow the new style in Angular 18?.
